# Ubuntu 18.04 mobile user profiles

Tags: 18.04, user-profile

I am curious if anyone has ever tried or found a toll for cloud syncing of user home directories on Ubuntu 18.04.

Basically I have a User on Ubuntu 18.04 laptop and I want to be able to use the same user (with everything inside) on a different PC.

I think this would require central cloud repo on some vps.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this method but I think Déjà Dup tool (backup and restore tool) should work.

Déjà Dup has google drive option which in your case can central cloud repo.
Create a backup on one system and restore it on other.

Or if you can ssh your old system, `rsync` is a better way to replicate home folder.